# Why the multitenant angular application has no role? (AzureAD + C# + Angular)

Tags: c#, angular, azure-active-directory, msal-angular

I registered two applications in AzureAD, both were set to multi-tenant, added users and gave them roles.
In my c# code, [I set tenant_id to "/common"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KadwC.png)

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {                    
                    options.Audience = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd_ResourceId");
                    options.Authority = $"{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd_Instance")}/common";
                    
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = $"api://{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd_ResourceId")}",
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    };
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            if (!context.SecurityToken.Issuer.StartsWith("https://sts.windows.net/"))
                                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
                });
```

[I also put "/common" in the angular application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5TVC.png)

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.uiClientId,
      authority: environment.tenantId,
      redirectUri: environment.appUrl,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.appUrl
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE // set to true for IE 11
    }
  });
}
```

I ended up getting a 403 response because there is no role in the received token
[403 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHWK2.png)
[No valid token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZLur.png)
Also I don't understand why my swagger application gets the user role correctly in the token even though they are exactly the same registered?
[Valid token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkyar.png)
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for help!